# Rewrite .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I'd like to rewrite an url but I can't get it working. Here's my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{4})$ /default/index.php?action=action&id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is this going to redirect to /default/index... ?

I don't understand what's happening..

Thanks !

Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what you're trying to do but, You're rewriting a string formed by 4 capital letters to /default/index.php?action=action&id=$1 where $1 is the value of the 4 letter from the original string

For example if you type in the browser :

```
yourhost/ABCD
```

your server will receive this request :

```
yourhost/index.php?action=action&id=ABCD
```

Maybe you want to use a case insensitive rule, or your rewrite base is not set correctly...but these are only supositions

Comment: ok, that's what I'm trying to do, thanks ! But it doesn't redirect me correctly : in fact it's giving me a 404 to a file that doesn't exists... Do you know where I could check if all the conf files are good with this ? Cause I'm quite lost here....

Comment: is mod_rewrite installed on your server??

Comment: Yep, it seems like it is installed. My server is on Debian and I used the a2enmod rewrite command to run it. Then I restarted my server

Comment: seems that either the module is not installed or the rule is not working as you expect

Comment: check your access.log to see what the server is receiving

Comment: ok, I checked the log and it was empty. But I found what happened : the admin in my company was not redirectiong it correctly. That's ok now, I thought it was my .htaccess but in fact no. Thanks anyway, you've help me to better understand it cause it was not my file! :)